# How will Kalki avatar happen ? Will Hinduism not exist at the time of his birth?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, kalki

What will be the situation of India or Hinduism when Kalki will take birth ? Will Hinduism be almost dead by then ?

Comment: Read this https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch08.htm